# Is this statement true, and how can I prove it?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Suppose we got a tree of probablities, of non independent probablities like this:

Path-1 : 0.5*0.7*0.8*0.9 = 0.252

Path-2 : 0.5*0.8*0.8*0.9 = 0.288

Path-3 : 0.6*0.9*0.7 = 0.378

suppose the probablity is the probablity of success, thus the highest probablity path, is the path we would like to pick.

now I have a hunch that if we do the sum like these:

Path-1 : (1-0.5)+(1-0.7)+(1-0.8)+(1-0.9) = 1.1

Path-2 : (1-0.5)+(1-0.8)+(1-0.8)+(1-0.9) = 1

Path-3 : (1-0.6)+(1-0.9)+(1-0.7) = 0.8

and we pick the smaller sum, its the path with the highest probablity of success.

is this idea correct? how if so how do I prove it, if not why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it’s not guaranteed. Consider the following two paths (for a possible tree with first branch probabilities 0.4,0,6):

```
Path 1: 0.4, 0.9
Path 2: 0.6, 0.69
```

Path 1 has a smaller sum (i.e. negative. sum as in your method) , but Path 2 is more likely.

From an algorithmic point of view, It is also counter intuitive to find the maximum value of an expression that involves multiplications via only summations.

Comment: I see, thanks for the example, what if the sum of log(value) is bigger, than its the path you'd like to pick? for example Log(0.4*0.9) < Log(0.6*0.69)

Comment: Yes, you can use logarithm